# Press delete, clear contents of another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using a script to insert a timestamp when a cell is edited. The timestamp inserts correctly, however I can't get the timestamp to clear out when I press the delete key on the reference cell. Any ideas?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Week 1" ) {
var col = e.source.getActiveCell().getColumn();
if(col == 1) {
  var nCell = e.range.offset(0,3);   
  if(e.value != "" ) {
    nCell.setValue(new Date());
  } else { 
    nCell.setValue(""); //doesn't seem to work if I simply press the delete key
  }
  }
 }    
}
```

Comment: My idea is that e.value is not equal to "" after the delete key is hit. Hitting delete is putting in the timestamp again.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. @iMarketingGuy's answer fixed this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to run the script from the script editor, I got an error *TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined*

This worked for me...

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Week 1");

  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var col = cell.getColumn();

  if(col == 1) {
  var value = cell.getValue();
  var nCell = cell.offset(0, 3);   
    if(value != "") {
      nCell.setValue(new Date());
    } else { 
      nCell.setValue("");
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Thank you so much! Looks like the trick was to get the value of the reference cell first and then checking against that value. Got it working now. Thanks!

Comment: The only downside I see is that you can delete the time stamp even when there's a value in col 1. If that's an unintended consequence, you want to extent the function to account for that.